# What's the best way to describe an event in slow motion?

Tags: description

In my story I'm gonna have the main character's dog die. I want to make it seem like the dog's death is really quick, but the main character screaming is stretched out. What would the best way to go about doing this be?

Comment: Describe the death quickly but the screaming in more detail? Do you need something more precise than that?

Answer (score 2):

A good example of stretching time can be found in a short story ["Bullet in the brain"](https://rwwsoundings.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Three-Stories-by-Tobias-Wolff.pdf) by Tobias Wolff.

The methods available to the writer stretching time include setting, reminiscence, and narrative.

When bad things happen, our sense of time slows down because our limbic systems go into overdrive: presumably to try and remember more details so we can learn from the experience, provided we survive.

This can be represented as a profusion of detailed and concrete descriptions of the setting. Those details can evoke reactions from the character -- a sense of confusion, beauty or disgust are particularly effective because they enhance the otherworldly nature of experiencing life through a series of millisecond-long moments.  Both of these details and reactions can be effectively used to evoke reminiscences of the character, leading to time shifts taking the narrative to past, and conceptually future, events in the character's life.

Minimize the use of cliches and adjectives and adverbs in the final work since they tend to rob the moment of its uniqueness. They are fine in drafts, as placeholders for where you need to do more work.

Answer (score 1):

**Stretch Out the Description**

While it may not seem slow-motion, drawing out the Description to increase suspense can help give the effect.

How this works is that the protagonist would be in sudden shock.

They don't exactly know what happened

They remember a bullet (or blade or arrow) coming nearby

They know a loud noise occurs, something striking someone

They look in that direction, and see that it's their dog.

The world is slowing, and all they feel is anger, rage, and pity

All they can do is scream

They continously scream, the world is no longer at speed.

So, for the slow motion, have the narrative and writing be stretched out to sound slow, and for extra detail, be how the protagonist views it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a direct equivalent of slow motion camera, the exact same effect on the reader can be provided by switching into present tense if the story is otherwise told in past tense. It also has all the subtlety of switching to slow motion camera, by which I mean it's rather on the nose.

A more sophisticated method (which can be combined with tense switch or used on its own) relies on the fact that the amount of time a reader perceives is not proportional to the time that passed in-story, but rather to the amount of text. So give your reader a lot of text. Take your time to describe the scene. Focus on all the details that affect your hero emotionally, details that contrast with his emotion, and details that are caused by his emotional response (changes in his bodily functions, the sound of his voice echoing back when reflected from the nearby buildings, mud soaking his trousers as he drops to his knees in despair...). Feel free to include little asides about past events that the hero is reminded of (happy moments, times when they narrowly escaped danger together...). But avoid irrelevant stuffing that would only dilute the mood. And to create the sense of slow tempo, write it in long sentences and long paragraphs.

For the part the reader is supposed to view as fast, do the opposite. Be brief. Give as little detail as possible, and sure no asides.

Short sentences.

Short paragraphs.

Even short sections.

And a crude trick, akin to the tense switching?

Sentences with no verb.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible "businesses" that you can apply.

- Have there be some build up before the hero discovers the death.
- Startled birds or other evidence of the scream beyond hearing it.
- Hearing the scream rather than seeing the screamer.
- Echoes, replays, other repetition. Maybe by several listeners.
- Description of the depth of the scream and comparisons to other tortured sounds.

The idea is to stretch it on the page and so stretch it in the reader's mind. It's a delicate thing and can get tedious quickly. And there are clichés aplenty waiting for you.